# Plus symbols near some directory names in dired?

Tags: dired

I've noticed in recent versions of emacs that some directoies in a dired listing have `+` "plus" symbols near them (see image). Would someone be so kind as to explain the meaning? I have not been able to find an answer in the Ctrl-h m manual nor with Google searching. My version is 27.1 on linux.

[image]

Comment: What are the values of `dired-listing-switches`, `dired-actual-switches` and `dired-subdir-switches` in this buffer? What happens if you do `ls` on the command line with those switches in force? FWIW, mine are defaults: `-al` for the first, `-al` for the second and `nil` for the third and I don't see the `+`s, so I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that you've set up something differently and forgotten about it. You might want to look for `dired` in your init file and see if anything pops up.

Comment: The extended extensions mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/227852/what-does-a-mean-at-the-end-of-the-permissions-from-ls-l) would be part of the first columns.

Comment: Start by looking at the variables @NickD pointed you to, in particular `dired-actual-switches`, to see what `ls` is using. Then try `ls` outside Dired. If you see the + signs without Dired then it has nothing to do with Dired - it's your `ls` switches. To find out what + means in that case try `M-x man ls`.